# How to get OneLogin group members via API?

Tags: onelogin

There are two interfaces in `Groups` in the api reference document

url: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/groups/get-groups

`Get Groups`: https:///api/1/groups

`Get Group by ID`: https:///api/1/groups/:id

I need the interface to get the members of group, is there an interface like `Get Group Members` not listed? or I should achieve it in other way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.